# DIsplay full Order Summary on shipping steps while select shipping method

Tags: shipping-methods, checkout-summary

I need to show Order summary with Total and subtotal on shipping steps based on select shipping method. It displays like payment step. if change shipping method it will change subtotal and total on shipping steps.
[image]

[image]